# Phonegap build app does not work properly on android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I develop application using `cordova` and `Phonegap Build` to get web, iOS and Android versions. iOS version works just fine, but Android's one has some troubles. I.g. some images (that's not local) don't appear, some functionality doesn't work properly (there are no cases with any plugins). 
Strange thing that iOS is OK. Also when I try to debug the app via `weinre` using `phonegap`, both Android and iOS work properly. But when I install .apk file to android, some things go wrong. Any thoughts what might it be? Is there any way to debug already installed apk? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was that `cordova-plugin-whitelist` had stopped working for some reasons for Android version and my AJAX didn't work anymore. Also it turned out, that if you use `Phonegap Build` next form of including the plugin into `config.xml` doesn't work: `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.0.3"/>`

The decision is to put the next line instead of that one: `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />`. After I had deleted old plugin and installed this one it started working.